# SQLite join пустая таблица

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Имеются таблицы:

- **mods (INTEGER id, TEXT name, INTEGER version, INTEGER release, INTEGER modification)**
- **relations (INTEGER mod_owner, INTEGER mod_attached)**

Всё это реализует связь many-to-many и запрашивается как:

```
SELECT 
    m.id as Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.id) AS DepList 
FROM 
    mods m
JOIN 
    relations mrm ON  m.id = mrm.mod_owner
JOIN 
    mods t  ON  mrm.mod_attached = t.id or mrm.mod_owner = t.id
WHERE 
    m.name = "%s" 
    AND
    m.modification = (SELECT max(modification) FROM mods)
GROUP BY m.id
```

Результат:

```
+----+---------+
|Id: | DepList:|
+----+---------+
|4   | 2, 4    |
+----+---------+
```

Но в случае, если в таблице relations нет ни одной записи, связанной с %s, возвращается пустой результат, а необходимо, чтобы возвращалось

```
+----+---------+
|Id: | DepList:|
+----+---------+
|%id |         |
+----+---------+
```

Всем больное спасибо, поставил плюсы. Ошибка была в том, что я забыл указать в SELECT max(modification) WHERE name = %s, как всегда глупость..

Comment: Используйте LEFT JOIN

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать где конкретно? В первом или втором джойне? Поскольку я пытался и тот, и другой, но результат аналогичный - пустота

Comment: @Mike     
Не могли бы вы написать где конкретно? В первом или втором джойне? Поскольку я пытался и тот, и другой, но результат аналогичный - пустота

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN должен быть - см ответ

Comment: Правило простое, та таблица в которой может не оказаться подходящей записи должна быть справа от LEFT JOIN (или слева от RIGHT JOIN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    m.id as Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.id) AS DepList 
FROM 
    mods m
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    relations mrm ON  m.id = mrm.mod_owner
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    mods t  ON  mrm.mod_attached = t.id or mrm.mod_owner = t.id
WHERE 
    m.name = "%s" 
    AND
    m.modification = (SELECT max(modification) FROM mods)
GROUP BY m.id
```

Поскольку второй JOIN делается через первый - оба должны быть LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: 0 строки возвращены за 0мс из: SELECT 
    m.id as Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t.id) AS DepList 
FROM 
    mods m
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    relations mrm ON  m.id = mrm.mod_owner
JOIN 
    mods t  ON  mrm.mod_attached = t.id or mrm.mod_owner = t.id
WHERE 
    m.name = &quot;binnie_mods&quot; 
    AND
    m.modification = (SELECT max(modification) FROM mods)
GROUP BY m.id

Comment: а, я не обратил внимание на второй join - он через relations идёт же, его тоже надо делать LEFT OUTER в таком случае... подкорректирую ответ

Comment: Интересно, почему многие любят писать "лишние" слова, не видел еще ни одной СУБД где бы слово "OUTER" было бы необходимо или чем то отличалось от "LEFT JOIN"

Comment: @Eugene Bartosh я сделал как вы сказали, без изменений

Comment: @Hiron123 Тогда отлаживайте запрос по частям. делаете для начала выборку только из `mods` с сохранением всех условий из where, убеждаетесь, что результат есть. добавляете одну таблицу (`relations`), убеждаетесь, что записи не пропали и т.п.

Comment: @Mike большое спасибо

Comment: @Mike - ну да, вопрос привычки + человеческая натура - если не так как у меня значит наверняка неправильно )) Но для новичка я считаю надо с OUTER всегда давать - это ему сразу подсказка (outer - внешний - ага!)