# Выборка пустых строк Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица вида:

```
id_sim | sim_id_status | sim_user | sim_comp | sim_phone | sim_number
```

Из этой таблицы делаю выборку данных:

```
$sim = array();
$sim_query = $dbquery->query("SELECT id_sim, id_sim_status, name_sim_status, sim_user, first_name, middle_name, surname, dolzh, short_name_comp, sim_phone, sim_number FROM sim, company, sim_status, users WHERE sim.sim_user=users.users_id AND sim.sim_comp=company.id_comp AND sim.sim_id_status=sim_status.id_sim_status");
    $sim_query->execute();
    while($row_sim = $sim_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $sim[] = $row_sim;
    }

    return $sim;
```

Как видно, в блоке:

```
sim.sim_user=users.users_id
```

идет сравнение двух таблиц. Если в таблице **sim_user** будет NULL или 0, то строка целиком не выводится. Мне необходимо сделать, что бы выводилась, так как данное поле содержит информацию о пользователе только в том случае, если ему выдана данная sim.

Вопрос: как можно сделать вывод всех строк, в том числе и пустые? 
Читал и пробовал **LEFT JOIN** - не помогло. 
Если не сложно, прошу дать рабочий код. Или указать в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite join пустая таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639874/sqlite-join-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Comment: Используйте LEFT JOIN. И что значит "не помогло". приведите пример как вы его делали (в тексте вопроса). например вы могли не все условия касающиеся не обязательной таблицы вынести из where в ON, что уничтожило эффект от left

Comment: LEFT JOIN не надо "пробовать", это не тортик. Надо просто использовать

Comment: И к вопросу о коде. PDO - не тупая mysql, в ней не надо писать отдельный код, чтобы получить массив. Весь код укладывается в одну строчку, `$sim = $dbquery->query($sql)->fetchAll();`

Comment: Возможно действительно не правильно использовал LEFT JOIN. Сколько не читаю, везде отсылка именно к этому. Но не могу сообразить, как правильно составить запрос.

Comment: для этого надо запрос упростить. не шарашить в него 100500 полей и 2 таблиц, а потренироваться сначала на ДВУХ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как на счёт

```
SELECT id_sim, id_sim_status, name_sim_status, sim_user, first_name, 
 middle_name, surname, dolzh, short_name_comp, sim_phone, sim_number
FROM sim
JOIN company ON sim.sim_comp=company.id_comp
JOIN sim_status ON sim.sim_id_status=sim_status.id_sim_status
LEFT JOIN users ON sim.sim_user=users.users_id
```

Общий совет: не пишите

```
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.table2_id = table2.id
```

Пишите

```
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id
```

Так получается более чистый код, потому что вы оставляете `WHERE` для реальный фильтров а не для остатков синтакся `JOIN`ов

Comment: как насчет проголосовать за закрытие вопроса вместо того чтобы пережевывать одно и то же в сотый раз?

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно. Ранее я ошибся при использовании JOIN и использовал его только для sim.sim_user=users.users_id. Увидел свою ошибку. Спасибо