# Как одним запросом взять информацию из нескольких таблиц? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет!
Подскажите как одним запросом взять всю информацию о пользователе.
Я использовал такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_email ON users_email.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN users_home_number ON users_home_number.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN users_mobile_number ON users_mobile_number.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN users_work_number ON users_work_number.user_id = users.id
```

Но его минус в том что если например у пользователя не будет указан рабочий номер, то запрос вернет пустые поля.

Cтруктура БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite join пустая таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639874/sqlite-join-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Заменить `INNER` на `LEFT`

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN users_email ON users_email.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN users_home_number ON users_home_number.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN users_mobile_number ON users_mobile_number.user_id = users.id 
LEFT JOIN users_work_number ON users_work_number.user_id = users.id
```

И еще, писать `SELECT *` крайне не рекомендуется. Указывайте те поля, которые нужны