# Совмещение нескольких таблиц MySQL одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть три таблицы: likes - лайки, callback - новость, answer - комментарии
Я пытаюсь получить новость, количество лайков и все ответы к этой новости. Не получается. Соединяю три таблицы. Показывает всё правильно, пока я не добавляю третью таблицу - ответы. Выводит один ответ и не показывает остальные, а кол-во лайков начинает умножаться на кол-во невидимых комментариев.

```
SELECT count(likes.sum_likes), comment_callback, text_answer FROM callback LEFT JOIN likes ON callback.id_callback = likes.id_callback_likes RIGHT JOIN answer ON callback.id_callback = answer.id_callback_answer WHERE callback.id_callback = 128



Array
(
    [count(likes.sum_likes)] =>
    [comment_callback] =>
    [text_answer] =>
)
```

Comment: А как Вы собрались получать новость и все ответы по новости в одном запросе? Что Вы с такой выборкой будете делать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, собираюсь вывести на страницу саму новость, к ней оценку и внизу комментарии.

Comment: Получите из базы одним запросом новость с оценкой и выведите ее. А потом **отдельным** запросом получите все комментарии к ней

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, т.е. Вы не знаете как сделать подобное?

Comment: Подобное **не нужно** делать

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, язык SQL придумали для того, чтобы упростить жизнь. Смотрите шире: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/776161/272483)

Comment: Существуют как такие, так и многие другие: EXPLAIN SELECT tt.TicketNumber, tt.TimeIn,
            tt.ProjectReference, tt.EstimatedShipDate,
            tt.ActualShipDate, tt.ClientID,
            tt.ServiceCodes, tt.RepetitiveID,
            tt.CurrentProcess, tt.CurrentDPPerson,
            tt.RecordVolume, tt.DPPrinted, et.COUNTRY,
            et_1.COUNTRY, do.CUSTNAME
        FROM tt, et, et AS et_1, do
        WHERE tt.SubmitTime IS NULL
            AND tt.ActualPC = et.EMPLOYID
            AND tt.AssignedPC = et_1.EMPLOYID
            AND tt.ClientID = do.CUSTNMBR;

Comment: И получите статью на каждый комментарий. Гениально!