# Как сохранить строки со значением NULL в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, mysqli, запрос, inner-join, долгий-запрос

Появилась необходимость переносить очень много данных с совершенно неадекватной базы данных. Данные одного товара такие как заголовок, текст, аннотация и т.д. находятся в разных таблицах или в разных строках если все таки в одной таблице.
Я пишу SQL запрос на формирование одной таблицы из всей этой кучи, чтобы перенести в другую CMS. Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT obj.title AS cat1, obj2.title AS cat2, obj3.title AS cat3, obj4.title 
AS cat4, obj5.title AS cat5, cont.val_text AS content, price.val_float as 
price 
FROM elements as elem
INNER JOIN objects AS obj ON elem.id_obj = obj.id
INNER JOIN elements AS elem2 ON elem2.id_parent = elem.id
INNER JOIN objects AS obj2 ON obj2.id = elem2.id_obj
INNER JOIN elements AS elem3 ON elem3.id_parent = elem2.id
INNER JOIN objects AS obj3 ON obj3.id = elem3.id_obj
INNER JOIN elements AS elem4 ON elem4.id_parent = elem3.id
INNER JOIN objects AS obj4 ON obj4.id = elem4.id_obj
INNER JOIN elements AS elem5 ON elem5.id_parent = elem4.id
INNER JOIN objects AS obj5 ON obj5.id = elem5.id_obj
INNER JOIN content AS cont ON cont.id_obj = obj5.id
INNER JOIN content AS price ON price.id_obj = obj5.id
WHERE elem.id = 68 AND elem.is_deleted = 0 AND elem2.is_deleted = 0 AND 
elem3.is_deleted = 0 AND elem4.is_deleted = 0 AND elem5.is_deleted = 0 AND 
cont.id_field = 134 AND price.id_field = 135
```

Проблема в том, что у некоторых товаров цена - NULL и строки, содержащие цену как NULL убираются из выборки, а это минус товар. Как сделать, чтобы они оставались? Пробовал использовать конструкцию IF(price.val_float, 0, price.val_float) - не выходило.

UPD:
Я немного неправильно сформулировал изначально вопрос, не сразу заметил, что поле price не NULL, на самом деле его просто нет, т.е. у некоторых товаров нет этого поля и они убираются из выборки!
Дак получается как тогда сделать, чтобы если нет поля то оно добавлялось, но было NULL, например, или 0???

Вот пример одного товара, как у него хранятся поля в базе content. т.е. есть столбцы со значением и есть строки с айдишниками полей (изображение, контент, цена и т.д.), если это цена - ставится в одну колонку, а все остальные NULL, точно также с контентом и т.д. Благо заголовок находится вообще в другой таблице
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `left` вместо `inner`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite join пустая таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639874/sqlite-join-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Comment: только все условия, касающиеся присоединяемых таблиц, вроде `elem5.is_deleted = 0` перенесите из where в ON соответствующего left join, иначе никакого эффекта от left не будет

Comment: К сожалению, в возможном дубликате вопроса схожая тема, но ответа конкретного нет, там проблема связана с ошибкой автора

Comment: После обновления вопрос стал не понятен. В таблице поле либо есть, либо его нет и это касается всех записей. не может быть, что в одной записи поле есть, а в другой его нет

Comment: И в любом случае вопрос надо упрощать. для начала оставьте только пару таблиц на которых у вас уже наблюдается проблема, потом поменяйте inner на left, перенесите условия в on, если после этого проблема остается, тогда постарайтесь описать в чем она заключается. Если проблема решилась - начинайте добавлять дополнительные таблицы

Comment: Хотя кажется я начал понимать в чем проблема ... надо в вопросе структуру БД приводить, думаете легко ее в голове составлять вычитывая такой запрос строку за строкой ? Для начала вам надо решить откуда взять список объектов, которые точно должны попасть в выборку. найти таблицу из которой их все можно получить и вот именно с этой таблицы и надо начинать запрос, именно она должна быть в from

Comment: Да, я уже позже про структуру подумал! Ответ уже нашел, он кроется в переносе  AND cont.id_field = 134 в ON. Теперь я уже лучше понял как работают запросы! Стало все гораздо понятнее! Спасибо за наводку! Ради истории приведу в пример структуру одной из таблиц в вопросе!!!

Comment: На том скрине, который я добавил, как раз таки нет поля с id_field = 135 - это цена! А наименования полей находятся в другой таблице. Такая вот структура дурацкая!

Comment: Я бы назвал ее не "дурацкая", а "типичный EAV". В нем можно довольно быстро искать по любому полю и легко модифицировать структуру данных. А вот получение всех сведений о объекте это для EAV конечно очень тяжелая задача. И мне кажется было бы логичнее начинать запрос с objects из которого сразу выбрать все интересующие объекты и к ним уже цеплять атрибуты

Comment: EAV - почитаю! Я, по факту, все необходимые данные сформировал, дописываю скрипт для внесения данных в БД modx! Спасибо большое за информацию!