# Как выводить информацию с БД, если foreign key равен NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 3 таблицы в базе данных. Например:

```
 table1                       table2           table3
 --------------------------   --------------   --------------
 |idPK|column1|idFK2|idFK3|   |idPK|column2|   |idPK|column3|
 --------------------------   --------------   --------------
```

И есть SQL запрос который должен выбирать объединенные данные с трех таблиц

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE table1.idKF2 = table2.idPK 
AND table1.idFK3 = table3.idPK    
AND table1.column1 = "search";
```

За этим условием он будет выбирать данные только если существует idFK3 (при условии что idFK2 NOT NULL)

Как усовершенствовать запрос что бы он выводил информацию даже если `idFK3 = NULL`?

Comment: Вместо запятой в from использовать `LEFT JOIN' и все условия по второй таблице обязательно писать в ON этого джоина

Comment: @Mike напишите в ответ, отмечу Ваш ответ как верный

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite join пустая таблица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639874/sqlite-join-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0)

Comment: @Mike еще мне пишет такую ошибку" Неизвестный столбец 'table1.idPK' в 'on clause' "

Comment: @Mike изменил вопрос, теперь если можно помогите

Comment: но вы не привели запроса в котором он вам это выдает. Но скорее всего вы не упоминали table1 до этого ON или такого столбца действительно нет в той таблице

Comment: @badroid если вы так и не разобрались в новой проблеме, то лушче завести для нее отдельный вопрос.