# Написать запрос к СУБД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане! В программировании MySQL совсем новичок. Нужно написать SQL-запрос к СУБД MySQL, который выбрал из базы данных пользователей и их последние комментарии (по одному комментарию на каждого пользователя), при следующих таблицах:

```
CREATE TABLE `db_user` 
( `db_user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`balance` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `db_comment` (
`db_comment_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`db_user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Запрос, который мне удалось написать:

```
SELECT MAX(com.text), us.name FROM `db_comment` AS com, `db_user` AS us ;
WHERE com.db_user_id=us.db_user_id ORDER com.text;
```

не учитывает ситуацию, когда есть пользователи, у которых комментариев нет вообще - они не выведутся, а должны. Помогите пожалуйста исправить.

Comment: А что такое "последний комментарий" ? max(text) вам выдаст лексиграфически максимальный текст комментария. А понятия "последнего" ваша структура БД вообще не предусматривает, так как нет например даты комментария. И у вас тут на самом деле несколько вопросов. Касательно почему не выводит - потому что у вас простой join  (в виде запятой), а должен быть left join http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639874/

Comment: Кроме того, раз надо по каждому пользователю - то необходим еще group by. И конечно определиться с понятием "последний" и видимо делать подзапрос или решать другими методами (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545054/194569)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам понадобится MAX(), но применить его надо к `db_comment_id` — это лучший кандидат на определение "последнего комментария" в вашей структуре, где нет поля с датой-временем.

Если сгруппировать по пользователю (т.е. по `db_user_id`), то MAX(`db_comment_id`) вычислит соответственно последние комментарии каждого пользователя, если они  писали комментарии.

Чтобы учесть возможность отсутствия комментария, используйте LEFT JOIN, а чтобы обойти любимую новичками [ошибку группировки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705647/272885), примените JOIN дважды: один раз для вычисления MAX(), второй для получения любых полей из таблицы комментариев.

```sql
SELECT u.db_user_id, u.name, u.balance, c2.text FROM db_user AS u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT db_user_id, MAX(db_comment_id) AS db_comment_id 
  FROM db_comment
  GROUP BY db_user_id
) AS c1 ON u.db_user_id = c1.db_user_id
LEFT JOIN db_comment AS c2 ON c2.db_comment_id = c1.db_comment_id
ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8992d/46

Answer (score 0):

Такой:

```
SELECT users.*, comments.text FROM db_user AS users
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM 
      db_comment AS c 
      ORDER BY c.db_comment_id DESC
    ) AS cs 
    GROUP BY db_user_id DESC
  ) AS comments 
ON comments.db_user_id = users.db_user_id
```

Comment: Пишет что ошибка  syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(u.db_user_id)' at line 5

Comment: да, distinct в другом месте.. опечатка

Comment: В вопросе было "получить последний комментарий" пользователя, а ваш запрос выдаст пользователей много раз, по количеству комментариев у них и distinct тут не поможет

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8992d/1

Comment: А как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: @Andreevich группировкой. См. мой ответ. Пока не освоите группировки, distinct лучше вообще не трогайте —  его использут неправильно в 99% случаев. :)  Это, блин, антипаттерн какой-то. https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/2008/11/11/60752/

Comment: Да, действительно не вник в задачу. Попробовал переделать запрос по примеру из ссылки. Изменил запрос.

Comment: @user2042869 `SELECT * GROUP BY x` — это выстрел в ногу. не делайте так. если даже он сработает, то считайте случайно и временно. См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное за помощь :)  До Distinct я пока еще не дошел. Думаю скоро уже дойду и постараюсь освоить )) Спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: @Andreevich не спешите его осваивать, distinct вам не понадобится ;) И не забудьте отметить правильный ответ галочкой и раздать плюсы всем, кто заслужил.